# Child Fragment's onCreateView() not called when using Support lib v4 rev20

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I have a view on phones that goes like this:

`MainActivity` contains `PaymentsFragment`, which contains a `FragmentPagerAdapter`, which in turn contains 2 `TransactionsListFragments`.

**`PaymentFragment` sample code:**

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);


        mPaymentsPagerAdapter = new PaymentsPagerAdapter(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), this);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_payments, container, false);
        assert view != null;


        if (!isFirstRun)
            mPaymentsPagerAdapter.setOnTransactionClickListener(this);
        else
            isFirstRun = false;
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_payments_viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(mPaymentsPagerAdapter);
        PagerSlidingTabStrip pagerSlidingTabStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_payments_tabstrip);
        pagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(viewPager);


        return view;
    }
```

**`PaymentsPagerAdapter` sample code:**

```
  @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                TransactionsListFragment recurringPaymentsListFragment = TransactionsListFragment.newRecurringPaymentsInstance();
                recurringPaymentsListFragment.setOnTransactionClickListener(mPaymentsFragment);
                return recurringPaymentsListFragment;

            case 1:
                TransactionsListFragment paymentsListFragment = TransactionsListFragment.newPaymentsInstance();
                paymentsListFragment.setOnTransactionClickListener(mPaymentsFragment);
                return paymentsListFragment;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Inside `TransactionsListFragment` there's nothing much going on. Besides, neither its onCreate() nor its onCreateView() are called, so I presume there's something wrong in either `PaymentsFragment` or `PaymentsPagerAdapter`.

The thing is, all the code was working flawlessly before upgrading to Support v4 lib rev20. I downgraded to rev19 and it was working again. So, any ideas on what is causing this to fail in rev 20, or is it a bug ? Also, what would be the workaround, if any ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently something changed with `setRetainInstance()` method inside the support library starting with v20, continuing onto v21 alongside Android 5.0.

As soon as I removed `setRetainInstance(true)` from the parent fragment, it worked.